# Creating a Caesar cypher; I do not understand the origin of the indentation issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am new to python and currently working on a project that requires me to create a caesar cipher.
I have defined a function called caesar as shown. However, I keep getting the error "unexpected indent" after the **else** statement. What I am I doing wrong?
'''

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt:\n")
text = input("Type your message:\n").lower()
shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))

def ceasar(plain_text, shift_amount, text_direction):
    cipher_text = ""
    for plain1 in plain_text: 
            position = alphabet.index(plain1)
            if text_direction == "encode":
                new_position = position + shift_amount
                new_letter = alphabet[new_position]
                cipher_text+=new_letter
        print(f"The encoded text is {cipher_text}")
            else:
                text_direction == "decode":
                new_position = position + shift_amount
                new_letter = alphabet[new_position]
                cipher_text-=new_letter
        print(f"The deoded text is {cipher_text}")

ceasar(plain_text=text, shift_amount=shift, text_direction = direction)
```

'''

Comment: I’d presume the `print` statements should be at the same indentation level as the lines above? Currently, they are telling Python, ‘the block is done, return to the outer level’.  But then, Python sees an `else` without an `if`, because Python was told the block had ended.

Comment: The *for* loop should not be indented. It needs to be aligned with the assignment to *cipher_text*. The remainder of your indentation will depend on the logic of this code. Indentation is critical in Python. Try: https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/

Comment: @S3DEV when I do what you've indicated, I get the error " text_direction == "decode":
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax" on line 18.

Comment: That line ends with a `:`; either that's an error, or you intended to use an `elif` claus like `elif text_direction == "decode":`.

Comment: You might want to review [this part](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) of [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

'''You have done,
***text_direction == "decode"*** is wrong because  "==" is comparison which can  be
only be used with **if...else condition**, but you used it wrongly.
you can check the output for the confirmation of this program.
Also, **I have corrected identations**, please compare or copy my solution
Happy coding '''

```
    def ceasar(plain_text, shift_amount, text_direction):
        cipher_text = ""
        for plain1 in plain_text: 
            position = alphabet.index(plain1)
            if text_direction == "encode":
                new_position = position + shift_amount
                new_letter = alphabet[new_position]
                cipher_text+=new_letter
                print(f"The encoded text is {cipher_text}")
            else:

                ### AFTER ELSE NO NEED TO USE "text_direction" == "encode" 
                ### and IDENTATION IS ALSO WRONG HERE

                new_position = position + shift_amount
                new_letter = alphabet[new_position]
                cipher_text-=new_letter
                print(f"The deoded text is {cipher_text}")
```

[image]